# Apple sign in with firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, apple-login

ers,

I am having some issues implementing both app and webapp sign ins for apple through firebase.

My issue seems to be that I am using OAuth on both app and webapp but the app side doesn't have a redirect uri. I have added a ServicesID but I can't use both AppId and ServiceID in firebase.

AppID: com.app.app
ServiceID: com.app.webapp

If I put in firebase the AppID it works perfectly on the app and vice versa.

Also I have already linked my Apple Sign In service to my AppId but still no luck.

Error is:

invalid_request
Invalid web redirect url.